# All in for less than big blind, post flop

Tags: rules

So, how are rules handled in this case?

Big blind amount is: 100

Player in question has 150 and calls big blind in the pre-flop round (and now has 50 left)
Post-flop, Player 1 is the first to act and goes all in for 50.  What can other players do?  Player 1 did not post a qualifying bet, did he?  How do re-raise rules apply here?  Calling rules?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Preflop, I supposed everybody limped.

Postflop, two pots will be created: a main pot and a side pot. The main pot has the 50$ of the hero and 50$ from all that want to play. The side pot contains all the money that the other players bet, **the hero not having the right to play in, thus not claim it.**

The main pot goes to the player with the best hand, the side pot goes to the player with the best hand at showdown or after everybody folded. The side pot will never be contested by our hero.

If you fold, you give up the claims for both pots.

Comment: what would be the minimum raise amount for other players?

Comment: A min-raise. The rules are the same

Comment: The min raise amount would be a min-raise? Would this be 2x the previous raise or 1 BB (i get that in this scenario its the same. but if the initial all-in was $90?)

Comment: 2x previous raise. An amount equal to the short stack's amount goes to the main pot and the rest goes to the side pot.

Comment: No. It's not 2x the previous bet [although in this EXACT case 100 is two times - thats a coincidence]. It's 2x the last bet, or the BB, whichever is GREATER. If the bet was all in $2, you cannot raise to $4, you still must complete to $100. In this case, the min raise would be $150, because 50 is half, and thus a full bet.

Comment: @sakon If the initial bet was $90, the first raise would be to $190. If the initial bet was $9, you can complete to $100 or fold. $50 - half OR MORE, is a full bet, and can be raised to $150.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends if it's limit, or no-limit.**

In limit, less than half a bet is a partial bet that can either be completed, or called. Half or more can be called, or raised [in this case to $150]. So his $50 bet doesn't actually count as a bet [usually there are 3-4 raises allowed, the $50 doesn't count as a raise or bet]

No limit, an opening bet is just an opening bet. The subsequent players can do whatever they want, but they must RAISE at least the BB. So in NL, you could call $50, raise to $150+ or fold.

In NL, an all in raise of less than half the required amount, can either be called or folded to, you cannot re-raise.

There is a lot of variation in this though. Most rooms have slightly different rules, and only about 75% of floor people will get it right in any particular room. You'll generally get a different rule in the morning than at night.

Answer (score 0):

Player after all in can call or raise.the raise would have to be size of bb, which is 100. So call, or 150. Other players follow same rule as first in after all in.